# Grouping by values in an array with AG-Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

Is it possible to group by values in an array with Ag-Grid? The examples with complex objects which use a keyCreator return only 1 key per row. I've tried this and it doesn't work.

Here is a simple example:

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';


const Example = () => {

  const rowData = [
    {name: "row1", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]},
    {name: "row2", tags: ["tag2", "tag3"]}
  ];

  const columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
    {headerName: "Tags": field: "tags", enableRowGrouping: true}
  ]

  return (<AgGridReact
    rowData={rowData}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    rowGroupPanelShow={'always'}
    modules={[ClientSideRowModelModule, RowGroupingModule]}
  />)
}
```